# What does "String[]::new" mean?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I'm learning how to use stream, and I get a problem with this method.

```
public static String[] inArray(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
   return Arrays.stream(array1)
  .filter(str -> Arrays.stream(array2).anyMatch(s -> s.contains(str)))
  .distinct().sorted().toArray(**String[]::new**);
}
```

I'm so confused about `String[]::new`, could you give me a hint?

Comment: It is an array creation

Comment: @xshe2:I understand that in your example, you want to put the focus on String[]::new using the **, but I find this rather confusing.
I would prefer to put a comment ->
 .distinct().sorted().toArray(String[]::new); // can you explain me what String[]::new) is about?

Answer (score 16):

`String[]::new` means `size -> new String[size]`.

When [`Stream#toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) is ready to produce an array, it calls `generator` and passes ([`generator.apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html#apply-int-)) the size of the inner collection to get a collection to fill it up.

Answer (score 10):

I would say the existing answers provide some insight but none of them yet talk about [`IntFunction<R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

To add to them explain, what it means in the context of `Stream.toArray(String[]::new)` is that it represents an `IntFunction` implementation such as :

```
new IntFunction<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public String[] apply(int value) {
        return new String[value];
    }
}
```

where the code creates a newly allocated `String[]` of size `value` and produces the array of that size as an output.

Answer (score 6):

You are right to be confused, because Java isn't really super clear about types vs. classes.

We know that `String[]` is a type, as you can declare variables of that type:

```
jshell> String[] s = new String[]{"Hello", "world"}
s ==> String[2] { "Hello", "world" }
```

However, `String[]` actually *is* treated as a class in Java and not just a type:

```
jshell> s.getClass()
$2 ==> class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

That funny looking `[Ljava.lang.String`, representing the type "array of string" shows up in response to the `getClass` invocation. I agree that it is surprising. But every *object* in Java has to have a class, and `String[]` is that class. (In other languages, you might see something like `Array<String>` which might be a dash clearer. But then Java has type erasure so again, things look a little confusing.)

In your particular case, here's what's going on. You need to be careful with types when making arrays from streams. Naively, you might get:

```
jshell> Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().toArray()
$5 ==> Object[2] { "a", "b" }
```

So we want the [version of `toArray` that gives us an array](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray%28java.util.function.IntFunction%29):

```
jshell> Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().toArray((n) -> new String[n])
$7 ==> String[2] { "a", "b" }
```

That's better! The result type is an array of strings, instead of just an array of objects. Now the `(n)->new String[n]` can be replaced with a method reference for construction. Java allows array types in method references! So we can write:

```
jshell> Arrays.asList("a", "b").stream().toArray(String[]::new)
$8 ==> String[2] { "a", "b" }
```

Aside: There are some caveats when using array types in method references like this, such as the requirement that the array type must be reifiable, but I think that's a little beyond what you might have been asking. The TL;DR here is that, by design, Java allows array types in (constructor-like) method references with `::new`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a method reference expression see [JLS 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).  The syntax for method references is:

```
MethodReference:
    ExpressionName :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
    Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
    ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
    super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
    TypeName . super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier
    ClassType :: [TypeArguments] new
    ArrayType :: new
```

The particular case you are looking at is the last one.  In your example, `String[]` is an *ArrayType* which means that it consists of a type name followed by one or more `[]`.

> There shouldn't be a class named String[] which is very lame and I could not interpret what it is actually meant for.

See above: it is a type *specification* not a class name. From a syntactic / linguistic perspective, this usage is analogous to:

```
  Class<?> c = String[].class;
```

or

```
  if (a instanceof String[])
```

or even

```
  public void myMethod(String[] arg)
```

(You wouldn't call those "lame" ... would you?)

---

Now you could have a valid case for saying that it is syntactically *unexpected* (especially to a pre-Java 8 programmer) to be able to use the `new` keyword like this.  But this unexpected syntax is a consequence of the strong imperative that the designers have to NOT break backwards compatibility when adding new language features to Java.  And it is not unintuitive.  (At least, I don't think so.  When I first saw this construct, is was obvious to me what it meant.)

Now, if they were starting with a clean slate in 2018, a lot of details of the Java language design would be simpler and cleaner.  But they don't have the luxury of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [Stream#toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) says it exactly:

> The generator function takes an integer, which is the size of the desired array, and produces an array of the desired size.

for example:

```
IntFunction<int[]> factory = int[]::new;
//                     v--- once `apply(3)` is invoked,it delegates to `new int[3]`
int [] array = factory.apply(3);
//       ^--- [0, 0, 0] create an int array with size 3
```

`String[]::new` is a [method reference expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) and it must be [assigned/casted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) to a certain functional interface type at compile time:

> A method reference expression is used to **refer** to the invocation of a method without actually performing the invocation. Certain forms of method reference expression also allow class instance creation (§15.9) or array creation (§15.10) to be treated as if it were a method invocation.
>
> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a **functional interface type** (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

### Edit

As @Eugene mentioned in comments below. It's necessary to let you know **how** and **where** the stream create an fixed size array to collecting all elements.

The following table is showing the stream **how** to calculates the array size:

- sequential stream - [AbstractSpinedBuffer#count](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/AbstractSpinedBuffer.java#107)
- parallel stream

  - stateless OPs with known/fixed size Spliterator - [AbstractConcNode#AbstractConcNode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Nodes.java#757)
  - stateful OPs

    - fixed size `Spliterator` - [Spliterator#estimateSize](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Spliterator.java#395)
    - unknown size `Spliterator` - [AbstractConcNode#AbstractConcNode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Nodes.java#757)

The following table is showing the stream **where** to creates a fixed size array by array generator `IntFunction`:

- sequential stream

  - stateful/stateless OPs with unknown/fixed size `Spliterator` - [SpinedBuffer#asArray](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/SpinedBuffer.java#214)
- parallel stream

  - stateless OPs with known/fixed size Spliterator - [Nodes#flatten](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Nodes.java#469)
  - stateful OPs

    - fixed size `Spliterator` - [Nodes#collect](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Nodes.java#324)
    - unknown size `Spliterator` - [Nodes#flatten](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Nodes.java#469)

Comment: if you *highlight* that this is actually `size -> new String[size]`, it would make it instantly clear IMO. plus one

Comment: @Eugene yes, sir. but others has already clarified. I only want to clarify **what** and **how** to use a method reference expression. because the OP confused about it.

Comment: well if you are on that path, you could say where that `size` comes from in `String[]::new`... especially since the OP uses `filter` that would break the `SIZED` property of the Spliterator. But that would be way too much probably as he says : `I'm learning how to use stream`

Comment: @Eugene good idea. could I add it in my answer simply to clarify how a `String[]` created with a special size?

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @Eugene Excuse me, sir. it's too late last night. How about this now?

Comment: yes and no :) what I meant to say is that if there are no `filter` or `flatmap` operations - that do change the size of the Stream - then it is obvious. On the other hand if intermediate operations do change it's size, it uses `SpinedBuffer` and then creates an array from that...

Comment: @Eugene :)..., maybe I think about it too more.

Comment: it's called "overthinking", yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[]::new
```

This is lambda for the following method:

```
public String[] create(int size) {
    return new String[size];
}
```

Comment: It is a `method reference` and is not really referring to the method you're presenting..

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not a lambda, and won't be equal to that lambda.  But it is certainly *functionally equivalent* to that method, or a lambda that does the same thing as that method..

Comment: Combining the two excellent comments, one might say "it is a method reference that is functionally equivalent to the lambda `(size)->new String[size]` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your whole stream operation is terminating converting that into an array, that is what you do with the last method **toArray()**, but an array of what?....
of **Strings** ( thus **String[]::new**)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `toArray(...)` is a Functional Interface (namely `IntFunction<R>` and then `String[]::new` is defined as the Method Reference or in that case constructor to use that generates an array of the desired type.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

And https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310341/16320675) of  [Andrew Tobilko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922375/andrew-tobilko):

> *"`String[]::new` means `size -> new String[size]`"*

which, since `toArray` takes an `IntFunction`, is similar to:

```
IntFunction<String[]> generator = new IntFunction<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public String[] apply(int size) {
        return new String[size];
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert your stream to another List, you can use:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't think your answer is relevant to the question being asked here.